# Use of 'with' or 'to' in the context of wedding invitation

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, collocation

I have come across the following 2 different usages in wedding invitations. May I know which of these is the right usage - marriage of ABC with XYZ or marriage of ABC to XYZ

Comment: What makes you think that only one of them is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both, though I would say *to* is more common.

*And* is also used, especially if not using the convention where the parents of the bride invite guests "to the marriage of their daughter, [BRIDE NAME] to [GROOM NAME]", which is still common today but not universal (the couple may send the invite themselves, there may be two or no brides, they may just prefer *and* as having a more egalitarian nuance, etc.)

Comment: I agree that "and" is a better fit than "with".  It is two different perspectives.  "With" or "and" focuses on the function or action of marriage.  "To" focuses on one person in relation to the other, and carries some traditional role connotations.